# BottomSheetFragment with edit text does not move up on opening softwindowkeyboard

Tags: android

I have an application with an activity  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Inside that activity there is an fragment and inside that fragment we are showing 
`BottomSheetFragment` with an edit text. While open that bottom sheet while getting focus from edit text soft window keyboard is open and its overlap the current `bottomSheetFragment` i.e `BottomSheetFragment` does not resize or move

Comment: try changing android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: @vrund not working in my case

Comment: It is working in phone with lollipop and higher version while it is not working in tablets with kitkat